# Delete Null Duplicates from DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to delete duplicates from one row, if the value in another column is null. Here's a sample dataframe:

| Primary Application | Assigned To |
| --- | --- |
| Application 1 | Jim Smith |
| Application 1 | nan |
| Application 2 | John Williams |
| Application 2 | nan |
| Application 3 | nan |
| Application 3 | Sarah Smith |

I'm trying to write a conditional that deletes the duplicate in *Primary Application* if the first or second value of a duplicate in *Assigned To* is null.

The ideal output would be:

| Primary Application | Assigned To |
| --- | --- |
| Application 1 | Jim Smith |
| Application 2 | John Williams |
| Application 3 | Sarah Smith |

Here's what I've written so far:

```
df = df.groupby('Primary Application', as_index=False).apply(
    lambda x: x.drop_duplicates(subset=['Primary Application'], keep='first'
    if x['Assigned To'].iat[1].isnull()
    else x.drop_duplicates(subset=['Primary Application'], keep='last')))
```

The main issue is with the if statement regarding isnull(). I've also tried using *is none* which hasn't worked either.

**A key thing I should have added to this question:** there are NA values I do want to keep, just not ones that are duplicates with what's already been assigned.

Comment: Sort first then logic becomes easier.

Comment: How about simply `df.dropna()`?  Or is there more complexity that I am not understanding?

Comment: it has to be a duplicate in "primary application" too

Comment: If the nan occurs e.g in the third row of the group, shouldn't it be deleted?

Comment: @jch I should have clarified. There are NA values in this dataframe that I want to keep, but they're not duplicates. Thus, I'm only deleting the NA values that are in duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a custom function to `groupby.agg`

```
import numpy as np

df.groupby('Primary Application', as_index=False).agg(lambda x: np.nan if x.isnull().all() else x.dropna(subset=['Assigned To']))
```

Comment: Getting an error on this one: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). This is a weird error because your code has .all(), so not sure why that's coming up.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is via `transform()`. If the group size is one then keep it, otherwise keep all the non-nan's in the group.

With a couple additional cases to represent non-dup situations:

```
d = {'Primary Application': ['Application 1 ','Application 1 ','Application 2 ',
    'Application 2 ','Application 3 ','Application 3 ','Application 4 ',
    'Application 5 '],
    'Assigned To': ['Jim Smith',np.nan,'John Williams',np.nan,np.nan,'Sarah Smith',
    np.nan,'Mark Meed'  ]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

  Primary Application    Assigned To
0      Application 1       Jim Smith
1      Application 1             NaN
2      Application 2   John Williams
3      Application 2             NaN
4      Application 3             NaN
5      Application 3     Sarah Smith
6      Application 4             NaN
7      Application 5       Mark Meed

df[df.groupby('Primary Application') \
   .transform(lambda x: (x.size==1) | (~pd.isna(x)))['Assigned To']]

  Primary Application    Assigned To
0      Application 1       Jim Smith
2      Application 2   John Williams
5      Application 3     Sarah Smith
6      Application 4             NaN
7      Application 5       Mark Meed
```

Comment: This code works; however, I do need to keep NA values in this dataframe, I just want to get rid of the NA's that are duplicates. I just edited the question to add that in.

Comment: @datacleanup I think I accomplish that - reflected in the two additional cases.  I keep a NaN for a group that contains no dups.  Help me where I am missing the objective.

Comment: Your use case is correct, for some reason in my dataframe, all of the nan's go away. I'll have to look into it further. Thank you for this!